# Can hd wallets have different withdrawal permission levels?

Tags: wallets, erc-721, hd-wallets

Specifically, is it possible for a wallet to have a key which can spend an ERC721 collectible, but its child keys not?

Answer (score 1):

I believe this is the whole idea behind extended keys, the levels of permission granted. Without knowing the **Chain code**, The parent key the child key is derived from is protected.

[image: levels]

More Documentation on [Extended keys can be found here.](https://github.com/bitcoin/bips/blob/master/bip-0032.mediawiki#extended-keys)

Comment: Nice! Could `m/0/0/1`, for instance, have its permission levels restricted? That is, `m/0/0/0` can spend an asset held in the wallet, but `m/0/0/1` can only sign a proof of ownership and not send it to other wallets.

Answer (score 0):

From a contract perspective, I don't believe you'd be able to determine the path of an address or it's relationship to another.